# Как опубликовать телеграм бота?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Добрый вечер! Понимаю, что вопрос точно был и информации по нему много, но вся она какая-то децентрализованная. Подскажите, пожалуйста, самый простой способ размещение телеграм бота. Когда мой комп выступает в качестве сервера все работает. Теперь хочу его опубликовать, но никак не могу определится в сотнях туториалов: Хероку, AWS, платные бесплатные. Неужели это так сложно.

Comment: попробуйте себя в другой профессии

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNbLYL8vZnE&t=691s
минута 9:27, там про сервер..